# Recompose JavaScript arrays: m n-dim arrays --> n x m matrix

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have the following array structure (say: for a plot with 3 lines):

```
let series1 = [1,2,3,4]
let series2 = [2,3,4,5]
let series3 = [2,6,6,7]
```

But I also need the following structure (say: for a jexcel table):

```
let data = [ [1,2,2], [2,3,6], [3,4,6], [4,5,7] ]
```

What would be the shortest way to create A from B (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to create the desired output is using `.map()`, `.forEach()` combination.

Please find my example below:

```js
let series1 = [1,2,3,4];
let series2 = [2,3,4,5];
let series3 = [2,6,6,7];

const arrays = ['series1', 'series2', 'series3'];

const result = series1.map((c,i) => {
  const a = [];      
  arrays.forEach(e => a.push(eval(e)[i]));      
  return a;   
});

console.log(result);
```

With the provided solution the code expects all the series arrays to have the same length.

I hope that helps!